# C++ BST - Call display() function without recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I created a BST using C++. The display function calls recursively and the program works fine.

However I want to display the BST without recursion. How do I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int value;
    Node * left;
    Node * right;
};

Node * root;

class Tree{
public:
    Tree() {
        root = nullptr;
    }

    void _INSERT(Node * current, int data) {
        if (current == nullptr) {
            Node * temp = new Node;
            temp->value = data;
            temp->left = nullptr;
            temp->right = nullptr;
            root = temp;
        }

        else if (current->value == data)
            return;

        else if (current->value < data && current->right != nullptr)
            _INSERT(current->right, data);

        else if (current->value > data && current->left != nullptr)
            _INSERT(current->left, data);

        else if (current->value < data && current->right == nullptr) {
            Node * temp = new Node;
            temp->value = data;
            temp->left = nullptr;
            temp->right = nullptr;
            current->right = temp;
        }

        else if (current->value > data && current->left == nullptr) {
            Node * temp = new Node;
            temp->value = data;
            temp->left = nullptr;
            temp->right = nullptr;
            current->left = temp;
        }
    }

    void _DISPLAY(Node * temp) {
        if (temp != nullptr){
            _DISPLAY(temp->left);
            cout << temp->value << endl;
            _DISPLAY(temp->right);
        }
    }

    ~Tree(){
        root = nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    int value;
    Tree obj;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("input.txt");

    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("input.txt");

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        value = (rand() % 500) + 1;
        outFile << value << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        inFile >> value;
        obj._INSERT(root, value);
    }

    obj._DISPLAY(root);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am thinking that I need to use Stack. If I push all the nodes and when the left-most node is NULL, then pop the values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably might be an easier solution, but this could get you started. Instead of preparing the stack for the whole tree, just store a flag on the stack showing if children have been already pushed on the stack. If not, just push the nodes including the one being processed on the stack in correct order. If yes, output the value:

```
void _DISPLAY(Node * temp) {
    std::stack<std::pair<Node*, bool>> stack;

    stack.push(std::make_pair(temp, false));

    while (!stack.empty()) {
        auto p = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        if (p.first == nullptr) {
            continue;
        }

        if (p.second) {
            std::cout << p.first->value << "\n";
        } else {
            stack.push(std::make_pair(p.first->right, false));
            stack.push(std::make_pair(p.first, true));
            stack.push(std::make_pair(p.first->left, false));
        }
    }
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/KFEK78421)